# How to update target list dynamically?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using the Community Edition. Daily I add new leads to the Sugar CRM database. We send newsletters using target lists. How can I update the target lists automatically before to start the emailing process? Ideally I would like to use a SQL statement or a report as a source of e-mail addresses for the emailing process. Is it possible?

The workflow is:

The user fill a order in our web. I need to add the record to the SugarCRM database.
According the user profile, he/she is assigned to a different target list. There are 4 target lists according the user profile.
Then, according the profile, the user will receive a different group of emails at 7, 15, 30 and 90 days from the registration date.
As I explain, a static target list does not work here because each day different users enroll in the system and the emailing schedule for each user depends on the date of registration.

I am trying to discover how to add directly via php to create dynamically a target list and then to launch the campaign but I am not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: You cannot do it out of box, but you can always customize things to achieve this thing. From my point of view, up on save, you can flash a popup showing drop down or multi select dropdown of target lists, you can link the lead created to select target lists.

Comment: If you want to automate the system, you can create a scheduler job to do it. Read leads created today, and create a new target list and all of those leads to it.

Comment: Will all new leads be added to the same lists all the time?  Or will some leads only go to certain lists under specific circumstances?

Comment: I have edited the initial question to explain it

Comment: Now that I see more details, it looks to me like this will need to be a scheduled task.  You could create a custom installable SugarCRM package, which adds a new scheduled task to SugarCRM.  This scheduled task will need to look at all the leads, and place them into the different lists based on their registration date.  Using PHP to execute SQL would be the route I take.  However there are alternatives that could be done in pure SQL.  Are you using SugarCRM On Demand, or hosting it on your own server?

Comment: I am using my own server and I can program in php and sql. I am not clear which would be the approach. As you say, the scheduled task would need to look at all the leads, and place them into the different lists based on their registration date, but at the same time, must it remove the "old" leads from the lists? If no, the "Launch" process would read again all records, the sent and not sent. Also, I am looking for how to start the launch process from php but I cannot find it.
Can I delete the "old" records from a target list and fill it again using the "new" records?

Comment: Please checkout the [filter](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Create_Custom_Filters) thing in vtiger. It allows to do such a dynamic query, I would like to see it too in sugarcrm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It is pretty simple. I only need to fill via sql the emailman table. I do not need to fill targets lists or similar.